# Corrupted image being saved by cv.SaveImage() in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

```
import sys, Image, scipy, cv2, numpy
from scipy.misc import imread
from cv2 import cv
from SRM import SRM

def ndarrayToIplImage (source):
"""Conversion of ndarray to iplimage"""
    image = cv.CreateImageHeader((source.shape[1], source.shape[0]), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
    cv.SetData(image, source.tostring(), source.dtype.itemsize * 3 * source.shape[1])
    return image

"""Main Program"""

filename = "snap.jpeg"
Q = 64

im = imread(filename)
name = filename[:-4]

img = Image.fromarray(im)

if img.size[0] > 200 or img.size[1] > 200:
    ratio = img.size[0]/img.size[1]
    size = int(ratio*200), 200
    img = numpy.array(img.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS))

    srm = SRM(img, Q)
    srm.initialization()
    srm.segmentation()
    classes, map = srm.map()

    """Converting ndarray to PIL Image to iplimage"""
    pil_img = Image.fromarray(map)
    cv_img = cv.CreateImageHeader(pil_img.size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
    cv.SetData(cv_img, pil_img.tostring(), pil_img.size[0]*3)
    print type(cv_img) ##prints <type 'cv2.cv.iplimage'>

    """Using ndarrayToIplImage function also gives the same error!"""

    """
    cv_img if of type iplimage but still gives error while using cv.ShowImage()
    or cv.SaveImage().

    There is no error displayed. Just the console hangs...

    """
```

I am using the SRM (Statistical Region Merging) Package available at [this page.](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~schwander/python-srm/)

I have just changed the example program given in the package. I had to convert the type returned by the SRM package functions to `iplimage`. There is no error in using the package but somewhere in using opencv functions.

This is the image that is saved after the console closes after hanging.
It used `cv.SaveImage()`.

[image: After getting error]

I tried `cv2.imwrite()` and I got this as the result:

[image]

This is the image that should have been saved. I used `scipy.misc.imsave('image.jpg', map)` to save this.

[image: Should have been!]

Comment: What happens if you try `cv2.imwrite()`? You don't need to convert to `IplImage`; it can save `ndarray` directly.

Comment: @Aurelius I even tried that but it did not help, though the console did not hang this time. I have edited the question asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use IplImage and PIL? SRM library read numpy array and you get a numpy array from `cv2.imread(image)`, then if you need to resize yuor image you can use opencv function `cv2.resize(...)`. Finally you can save an image with opencv with `cv2.imwrite(...)` your code should appear like this:

```
import sys, cv2, numpy
from SRM import SRM

"""Main Program"""

filename = "snap.jpeg"
Q = 64

img = cv2.imread(filename)
name = filename[:-4]


if img.shape[0] > 200 or img.shape[1] > 200:
    ratio = img.shape[0] * 1. / img.shape[1]
    size = (int(ratio * 200), 200)

    img = cv2.resize(img, size, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)

    srm = SRM(img, Q)

    srm.initialization()
    srm.segmentation()
    classes, srmMap = srm.map() # Map is a python function, use different variable name
    srmMap = srmMap.astype('uint8') # or you can try other opencv supported type 
    # I suppose that srmMap is your image returned as numpy array
    cv2.imwrite('name.jpeg', srmMap)
    # or
    cv2.imshow('image', srmMap)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```